# Take the last two items of a list with list and put in a list of pairs

Tags: haskell, arraylist

I just can't seem to get this to work...

```
finalPairs :: [String] --> [(String, String)]
finalPairs [] = []
finalPairs (x:xs)
            | length x >= 2 = (a,b) : finalPairs xs
            | otherwise = []
            where   a = (drop (length x - 2) x)
                    b = (drop (length x - 1) x)
```

I have tried multiple varieties. For example

```
finalPairs [] = []
finalPairs (x:xs)
            | length x >= 2 = ((init x), (drop (length x - 2) x) : finalPairs xs
```

There seems to be a problem with the "finalPairs xs" - recursion part. Can someone help me understand why this doesnt work and how to solve it?

Comment: Can you please provide sample input and expected output for clarity? Also, when you write `x:xs`, `x` is not a list but a single element, which is causing issues

Comment: "Does not work" is bad introduction to problem. Your results are different from what you expect? So post your input, your result and your desired result. Your code fails to run? So post the error code and text **as plain text**. You do not know how to write peace of code? So describe what do you try to accomplish.

Comment: `--` is the start of a *comment*, so `--> [(String, String)]` will be interpreted as a comma.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That's not quite correct -- `--` followed by punctuation is an operator name. The actual error you get is that `-->` is not in scope!

Comment: @shree.pat18 `x` *will* actually be a list here (assuming the `-->` was intended to be `->`), because `x :: String` and so equivalently `x :: [Char]`.

Comment: @DanielWagner: ah, yes. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner you are right of course. I meant that x will not be the list of strings that OP was expecting

Answer (score 1):

So a first problem is a syntax error that is going to give you a type error

you wrote: `finalPairs :: [String] --> [(String, String)]`

you need: `finalPairs :: [String] -> [(String, String)]`

My other advice when dealing with the end of Lists (AKA Strings) is to use the `reverse` function rather than trying to treat a them like it is they are arrays in C or Java.

Answer (score 1):

It really isn't completely clear to me what your function is supposed to do...

On the one hand, taking a list and turning it into a list of pairs of adjacent elements, that is one thing:

```
combine :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
combine (x:y:zs) = (x, y) : combine zs
combine [x] = [] -- throw away single, left-over elements?
combine [] = []
```

You could create a function that did the same, but from the back:

```
combineR :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
combineR xs = combine (reverse xs)
```

Or you could, uh, take *only* the pair of second-last and the last element and put them in a list with just that one pair... but then, why would you need a list as part of the result type?

```
huh :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
huh xs =
  case reverse xs of
    x:y:zs -> [(y, x)]
    _ -> []
```

While the first of these three is a pretty good exercise in recursion, it has limited practical value, and the other two are so hypothethical to me that I'm pretty sure there their interpretation is caused by unclarity in your question. Could you try and rephrase the question so that your task makes a little more sense?